# TSQL SELECT previous date's records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, datetime

I want to select all records from a table `Log` where the `DateAndTime` field values (of type `datetime`) are for the day before today, whatever day it is.

So if today is 2011-06-08, I want to select all rows where `DateAndTime` is greater than or equal to `2011-06-07 00:00:00` and also less than `2011-06-08 00:00:00`.

I'm guessing the potential pitfall here would be it's behaviour on the 1st day of the month, as obviously a date like `2011-06-00` is invalid, and should be `2011-05-31`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008 you can use this.

```
select *
from [log]
where cast(DateAndTime as date) = cast(getdate()-1 as date)
```

Pre 2008 you can use this

```
select *
from [log]
where DateAndTime >= dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, getdate())-1, 0) and
      DateAndTime < dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Related on DBA: [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)

Comment: Casting the column could have serious performance implications, see JanW's solution below

Comment: @AdriaanDavel Yes it can, with cardinality estimates. Not with sargability. Did you read the question on DBA linked from my answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM Log
WHERE DateAndTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
AND DateAndTime < CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 1):

This example assumes SQL Server:

```
select *
from log
where convert(varchar(8), DateAndTime , 112)  = convert(varchar(8), getdate()-1, 112)
```

Essentially, convert the date to yyyymmdd (the `112` parameter) and then check it is equal to yesterday's date (`getdate()-1`), also converted to yyyymmdd.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server

```
 declare @today date
 set @today = GETDATE()

 select * from Log where DateAndTime between DATEADD(dd, -1, @today ) and @today
```

Answer (score 0):

It should include **conditional operator** and not **between** .
Otherwise it includes today's records as well.

```
Declare @today date
Set @today = GETDATE()


Select YourcolumnNames from log
Where DateAndTime >= DATEADD(dd, -1, @today ) and DateAndTime < DATEADD(dd, -1, @today )
```

Moreover, you should mention the column name and * should be avoided in the select statement. This can improve the performance